# How to paint the color of the road between points geolocation?

Tags: javascript, road

We have sensors set on the map, each of them has  coordinates, we made a rectangle using Graham scan and for the moment we need to paint up all roads which are included into this rectangle. Can you advise which method we should use to make it? We have not found any example in ARCGIS API (version 3.18).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking just to show the roads with the extent as a different color? If so here is an example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_selectfeatures.html